# Simple Docker networking -- not sure where to even start

Tags: docker

I have a server 10.202.1.100, I'd like it to host 30 Docker VMs, 10.202.1.101 through 10.202.1.131.  I would like all of them to be able to access the network, access each other, and I'd like every host on our Intranet to be able to access them.

I'm not even sure where to start (all the examples are a bit more complex and a bit more security conscious that I require).

THANKS in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to answer, and easy at the same time. First up, Docker containers are not VM's. We typically suggest that a container is a wrapping, or package around one application - whereas VM's conceptually run an OS's entire init.

And in that context, we often try to avoid bridging containers onto your host network wholesale.

However, there are times and places that this is very very useful - so there are 2 answers:

1. if you need it *now* and don't want to run your own build of Docker - use https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework
2. if you're willing to build your own docker daemon, and help test the future - see https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/pull/4441

both these 2 should give you the ability.

Comment: An alternative way of approaching the problem would be to setup a Docker container with some kind of networking management API to which containers can register and ask about other registered containers. I'm sure there are many ways to do this, but if you are interested in that, you might want to ask a new question (other users have more experience in this than I).